# Why am I getting a system overflow using big integer (System.Numerics)?

Tags: c#, numeric, biginteger, system.numerics

I am getting this error: System.OverflowException: 'The value is not a number.'
I was under the impression that big integer could store any sized value (500 ^ 500 in this case), so I don't understand why this is happening.

```
public int decode(int code)
{
   int totient = (p - 1) * (q - 1);
   int d = modInverse(e, totient);
   int pq = p * q;
   BigInteger decodedMessage = new BigInteger(Math.Pow(code, d) % pq);
   return (int)decodedMessage;
}
```

Comment: What happes if Math.Pow() overflows?

Comment: `BigInteger` can, but the result of `Match.Pow` is a `double`.  You need to convert `code` to `BigInteger` first then do `BigInteger.Pow`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
BigInteger decodedMessage = new BigInteger(Math.Pow(code, d) % pq);
```

Well, `Math.Pow(code, d) % pq` is not a BigInteger, it's an expression of type `double`. Converting the *result* to a BigInteger won't have an effect until the computation is complete (and has overflowed).

`Math.Pow` can easily overflow to `Double.PositiveInfinity` with large numbers, and `Double.PositiveInfinity % someNumber` yields `Double.NaN`. Calling `new BigInteger(Double.NaN)` yields the error you have described.

You need to *do the computation* in BigInteger. Fortunately, there's a method for exactly that purpose ([BigInteger.ModPow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.biginteger.modpow?view=net-5.0)):

```
BigInteger decodedMessage = BigInteger.ModPow(code, d, pq);
```

(BigInteger.ModPow requires BigInteger parameters, but there are implicit conversions from int to BigInteger.)

Comment: Thank you, this fixed it

Answer (score 1):

It seems that `pq` is `0`, next throws the same exception:

```
new BigInteger(0.0 % 0);
```

Division of `double` by zero results in `Double.NaN` which is not a valid value to instantiate a `BigInteger` according to [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.biginteger.-ctor?view=net-5.0#System_Numerics_BigInteger__ctor_System_Double_):

> Exceptions
>
> OverflowException
>
> `value` is NaN, NegativeInfinity, or PositiveInfinity.

Or, as [@Heinzi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/87698/heinzi) correctly mentioned in comments `Math.Pow` results in Infinity.

Comment: Either that, or Math.Pow overflowed to PositiveInfinity. `PositiveInfinity % SomeNumber` also yields `NaN`.